# Writing a bash script to run a java program with command line arguments?

Tags: java, bash, unix

I have written a java program that maintains a database for bank accounts (This is a course assignment) and I want to create a bash script to run. Upon running the program, you have to input "i", "h", "t" or "?" to get it to perform a task. I would like to take those command line arguments and use them for when running this program in bash. For example, if the script were named accounts, I want to be able to type accounts -i and the script would launch the program with the i command already input and perform the task for that argument? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: see `man getopt` or `help getopts`.

Answer (score 1):

The best would properly be for your Java program to take arguments.

But I assume all of this is for educational purpose only, and that said Java program reads from standard input.

Usually configuration for a program should go as arguments:

```
$ ./my_program --configA --configB --optC=valD
```

But In your case it seems like you have an interactive program that prompts the user for questions:

```
$ ./my_program
Question 1?
> Answer1
Question 2?
> Answer2
```

`$` is command prompt, and `>` is user input.

Anyway one can feed standard input from a pipe, file, etc etc:

```
my_program1 | my_program2
```

Output from `my_program1` goes as input to `my_program2`.

```
my_program < my_file
```

Input to `my_program` is coming from a file `my_file`.

You can also feed input from a here documents, the syntax is `<<MARKER` and ends with `MARKER`:

```
my_program << NAME_DOESNT_MATTER
line1
line2
line3
NAME_DOESNT_MATTER
```

This will put three lines into `my_program`.

In bash it's simply to refer to positional parameters as they are called `$1`, `$2`, .. `$n`:

```
$ cat my_shell_program
#!/bin/bash
echo "$2" "$1"
$ ./my_shell_program "hello world" "John Doe"
John Doe hello world
```

Now you should be able to figure out the rest.